# Zabbix 3.0 MySQL database i cannot find databases/mysql schema.sql

Tags: mysql, database, zabbix

I am trying to build Zabbix Server 3.0, but i encountered this issue:
So i need to create a zabbix database with this guide:

```
    shell> mysql -uroot -p<password>
    mysql> create database zabbix character set utf8 collate utf8_bin;
    mysql> grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by '<password>';
    mysql> quit;
    shell> cd database/mysql
    shell> mysql -uzabbix -p<password> zabbix < schema.sql
    # stop here if you are creating database for Zabbix proxy
    shell> mysql -uzabbix -p<password> zabbix < images.sql
    shell> mysql -uzabbix -p<password> zabbix < data.sql
```

but when i get to `cd database/mysql` i don't really know where i should go, I tried `/var/lib/mysql` but then when i get to this step `mysql -uzabbix -p<password> zabbix < schema.sql` there is no `schema.sql` and i can't find it anywhere. So how can i find/create it or is it with a new name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed from source, you should do that from the source directory.

If you installed from package repositories, it depends on the distribution and repository.
For example, if you installed from the Zabbix repository on a RedHat system, the SQL might be located in `/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.0/create` .

Some packages might combine those three SQL files in one, so you will only have `create.sql.gz`. You can import it directly as "zcat create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix". If you want to see the SQL file, you can extract it with 'tar -xvf create.sql.gz' in a single step.

Comment: I am using CentOS 7  and I am installing it from repository.

Are you referring that i should unzip create.sql.gz ?

Comment: I've extracted create.sql.gz and it became just create.gz, so there is no schema.sql nor images.sql

Comment: Some packages might combine those three SQL files in one, so you will only have that single file. You can import it directly as "zcat create.sql.gz | mysql zabbix". If you want to see the SQL file, you also have to 'gzip -d create.gz' - or you could have used 'tar -xvf create.sql.gz' in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

When you install zabbix 3.0.x via zabbix official repository on RHEL 7.x or CentOS 7.x, you do not need to import `schma.sql`, `iamges.sql` and `data.sql` in Zabbix 3.x just like previous versions.

All you need is to import `create.sql` using this command `zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-*/create.sql.gz | mysql -uzabbix zabbix -p`

[Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/installation/install_from_packages) has more detail.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You still have to import schema, images and data. Some methods of distribution can pack all those files in a single archive like `create.sql.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found an answer or not, but there's a script bootstrap.sh that will generate your ./configure. You can generate the data.sql and schema.sql on your own as well by running

```
create/bin/gen_data.pl > database/mysql/data.sql
```

and

```
create/bin/gen_schema.pl > database/mysql/schema.sql
```

They are both perl scripts.

Comment: Please note that `bootstrap.sh` is not really related to generating the SQL files.

Comment: I no longer have access to the project, so I can't confirm nor deny what ou are saying.

Answer (score -1):

`database/mysql` is in the source.

For example download latest source from http://www.zabbix.com/download.php